# Implementation Random Forest Regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, random-forest

I've been studying and searching for information for days, both here and on the internet, but I can't reach a conclusion.

I've a nonlinear regression problem so I tried RF on R. This is my first ML algorithm implementation

```
#df is the dataframe 1268x9, X=1268x8, y=1268x1
# y are €, and range(y)=[0, 73000]
set.seed(123)
index <- sample(1:nrow(df), round(0.7*nrow(df)), replace = F)
data_train <- data[index, ]
data_test <- data[-index, ]

trcl <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, search="grid")
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(1:8))

ntrees <- c(seq(50, 250, by=50))
nodesize <- c(1:12)
params <- expand.grid(ntrees = ntrees, nodesize = nodesize)
store_maxnode <- vector("list", nrow(params))
```

now I search and tune parameters (ntree, nodesize, mtry) considering their interaction

```
for(i in 1:nrow(params)){
  ntree <- params[i,1]
  nodesize <- params[i,2]
  set.seed(123)
  rf_model <- train(y ~.,
                   data = data_train,
                   method = "rf",
                   metric = "RMSE",
                   tuneGrid = tuneGrid, 
                   trControl = trcl, 
                   importance = T, 
                   nodesize = nodesize,
                   ntree = ntree)
  store_maxnode[[i]] <- rf_model
}
```

Found the best parameters for my data! So my final model is

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "none") 
tuneGrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = 2)
rf <- train(y ~.,
                  data = data_train,
                  method = "rf",
                  metric = "RMSE",
                  tuneGrid = tuneGrid,
                  trControl = fitControl,
                  importance = T,
                  nodesize = 10, 
                  ntree = 150, 
                 )

prediction <- predict(rf, newdata = data_test)

RMSE <- sqrt(sum((df$y - prediction)^2)/nrow(prediction))
```

...RMSE=12000, slightly high. I tried different parameters and model form but RMSE is always around 11k -.-' Additionally
[image: Observed vs Predicted]

[image: Observed vs Residuals]

Do you have any suggest to obtain better results?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

Original df has 6 predictors(5 numerical, 1 categorical data), 1 outcome. In the code above I wrote

> X=1268x8

because I turned categorical feature into binary (categorical has 3 categories) to test other algorithms

[image]

Comment: You've got a typo in your code around `search="grid` - the quotes aren't closed properly

Comment: Thanks for fixing. Can you post the data used in your model? Or at least the `pairs()` plot given that it's only 8 predictors and an outcome

Comment: Done. Maybe the problem is the relation between X5 and X1? I've read many books and papers but the practice is more complicated.

Comment: I doubt it really; RF shouldn't really "care" about collinearity. You could probably drop one to see, though. I would say that looking at the pair plots with y it's not obvious that any of the individual features would have huge predictive power here?

Comment: Honestly, I don't find the graph very explanatory on that, I don't see any feature with huge predictive power on y. Given that I've only 8 predictors, can be useful drop one at time and see RF's output? It's a bad idea?